# How do I use this script to find why my recovery model changed from full to simple?

Tags: t-sql, ssms, recovery-model

I have found a post that has a script that will provide details for my question.  When I execute the script no results return.  What do I need to change within the script to return results for the change from full to simple recovery model?

```
DECLARE @tracefile VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ProcessInfoSPID VARCHAR(20);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#SQLerrorlog]
    (
        [LogDate] DATETIME NULL
        , [ProcessInfo] VARCHAR(10) NULL
        , [Text] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
    );

/*

Valid parameters for sp_readerrorlog

1 – Error log: 0 = current, 1 = Archive #1, 2 = Archive #2, etc…

2 – Log file type: 1 or NULL = error log, 2 = SQL Agent log

3 – Search string 1

4 – Search string 2



Change parameters to meet your needs

*/

--Read error log looking for the words RECOVERY

--and either FULL, SIMPLE or BULK_LOGGED indicating a change from prior state
INSERT INTO #SQLerrorlog
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'RECOVERY', 'FULL';

INSERT INTO #SQLerrorlog
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'RECOVERY', 'SIMPLE';

INSERT INTO #SQLerrorlog
EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'RECOVERY', 'BULK_LOGGED';

UPDATE #SQLerrorlog
SET ProcessInfo = SUBSTRING(ProcessInfo, 5, 20)
FROM #SQLerrorlog
WHERE ProcessInfo LIKE 'spid%';

-- Get path of default trace file
SELECT @tracefile = CAST(value AS VARCHAR(500))
FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT)
WHERE traceid = 1
    AND property = 2;

-- Get objects altered from the default trace
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS RowNumber
       , *
INTO #temp_trc
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@tracefile, DEFAULT) g -- default = read all trace files
WHERE g.EventClass = 164;

SELECT t.DatabaseID
       , t.DatabaseName
       , t.NTUserName
       , t.NTDomainName
       , t.HostName
       , t.ApplicationName
       , t.LoginName
       , t.SPID
       , t.StartTime
       , l.Text
FROM #temp_trc t
    JOIN #SQLerrorlog l ON t.SPID = l.ProcessInfo
WHERE t.StartTime > GETDATE() - 1 -- filter by time within the last 24 hours
ORDER BY t.StartTime DESC;

DROP TABLE #temp_trc;
DROP TABLE #SQLerrorlog;
GO
```

Comment: Source for the script?...I'd be surprised if you'd be able to find *why* it changed. As far as I'm aware, that's a database setting that's manually altered.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316855/how-do-i-use-this-script-to-find-why-my-recovery-model-changed-from-full-to-simp

Comment: This link to stack has the original source as well with some formatting changes.  I would settle for the who in terms of a SPID as opposed to the why.

Comment: It looks like you linked to your own Post somehow, lol.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214888/find-out-recovery-model-changes

Comment: My apologies J.D. I put the wrong link above is correct.

Comment: Gotcha, so your goal is really to find out who and when it changed?

Comment: Yes absolutely that is my goal.